# How to read in more than 250,000 characters XML CLOB field from Oracle into R or SAS?

Tags: r, sas

I need to read in this XML COLB column from Oracle table.  I tried the simple read in like below:

```
xmlbefore <- dbGetQuery(conn, "select ID, XML_TXT from XML_table")
```

But I can only read in about 225,000 characters.  When I compare with the sample XML file, it only read in maybe 2/3 or 3/4 of the entire field.

I assume R has limitation of maybe 225,000 characters and SAS has even less, like about only 1000 Characters.

How can I read in the entire field with all characters (I think it is about 250,000-270,000)?

Comment: I can query an 1.89M character `varchar` just fine through `DBI` and `odbc`, and while my query is against a SQL Server, I have no reason to believe that it is a limitation in R. What are you using that leads you to that assumption?

Comment: I was testing it in R and using the substring to break the text into 2 parts: substr(XML_TEXT,1,250000) as xml_text1, substr(XML_TEXT,225000, 500000) as xml_text2, Then I checked the Text2 I read in, it only have few lines read in. And the last line is not the last line of the entire XML that I got from oracle.

Comment: I also play with the number a little bit for Text2, then I found when I get to 227,283 this magic number, my text2 has no more text at all. So this is the limit that I can read in so far. substr(XML_TEXT,227283,500000) as xml_text2

Comment: Helen, it's difficult to really comment on that without something to play with. I can use `substr` on that 1.89M char string I mentioned, so it is in my mind not a limitation of R. I don't have your data, unfortunately, so it's hard to say much more than that and/or help. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Unfortunately, I cannot release the real data I have for example.

Answer (score 1):

SAS dataset variables have a 32k char limit, macro variables 64k.  LUA variables in SAS however have no limit (other than memory) so you can read your entire XML file into a single variable in one go.

PROC LUA is available from SAS 9.4M3 (check &sysvlong for details).  If you have an earlier version of SAS, you can still process your XML by parsing it a single character at a time (RECFM=N).